# Mybb login bug, login with other user's acc

Tags: php, authentication, forum, mybb

sometimes in my forum ( forexample once a mounth ) , if I login with my username and password, after login I found that I am login with other user's account !!!!!!

many of registered users have the same problem !!
Is this reported problem ???
How can i fix that ?

in addition, when this situation happens, I can see the list of the Private messages of that user (but can't open them and when click on them, or refresh the page, all things goes normall and I'm in my own account!)

I think it should be a session conflict...

Comment: How about your cookie path and cookie domain? And which MyBB version you are using? I'm using MyBB 1.8.X and never see your strange login issue.

Comment: Hi, no the cookie path is true. my forum online users are about 2000 at the same time and it is run on a dedicated server. we are using mybb 1.6.13 . I think it's from caching...

Comment: Well, if you put your forum in a sub-folder, then your cookie must be: `/directory/`. If you are not using www, then try one and your cookie domain will be `www.domain.com`. Then clear your cache and hope that's strange issue will not happen again. I don't think it's caused by MyBB, but your issue may come from your configuration.